# Have many UL element in my page but want to empty UL in a particular div

Tags: javascript, html

I have multiple `ul` elements in a `form` and I want to empty the `ul` elements in a particular `div`.

I have 2 `div`s, one with `id="first-ul"` and the other with `id="second-ul"`. All `ul` in both `div`s are dynamically created. Each `ul` element has a default `li` node with class name `y`. The rest of the `li` nodes are dynamically created and given class name `x`.

Now I want to empty the `ul` that exists in `div` with `id="second-ul"` but only leave the default `li` node which has class name `y`.

```html
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" id="form-data" action="#">
    <div class="form-group" id="first-ul">
        <ul class="select2-selection__rendered">
            <li class="x" >Annet Molly</li>
            <li class="x" >nohh kde</li>
            <li class="y"> Stay</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group" id="second-ul">
        <ul class="select2-selection__rendered">
            <li class="x" >Annet Molly</li>
            <li class="x" >nohh kde</li>
            <li class="y"> Stay</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to give you much advice without any kind of code, but using jQuery to access the data from your HTML, you can do something like this:

```js
var array = new Array();
$("ul#myDataList").find("li").each(function() {  
   

   var listItemValue = $(this).html();
   array.push(listItemValue);
   
});


$("#result").append(array + ", ");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="POST">
<ul id="myDataList">
 <li>Data 1</li>
 <li>Data 2</li>
 <li>Data 3</li>
</ul>
<!-- Do the rest of your form -->
</form>

<div id="result">
</div>
```